# How do I write a method that fills a property using the property's name?

Tags: c#, reflection

Here is what I am looking at doing. Say I have a Class with a number of properties. I am trying to write a method that looks something like this

```
       public static void GetNullableInt32(this DbDataReader reader, Type property)
       {
           property = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(property.name))
                         ? (int?)null
                         : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal(property.name));

       }
```

Where the property name is pulled from reflection, and the property is set in the method. I put in Type in the parameters as a placeholder for whatever type it needs to be. Then I would call it like

```
      reader.GetNullableInt32(Class.Property1);
```

To set all the properties on a class from a database reader.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or is there a better structure where instead of having to enter the column name as a string it is pulled from the column name?

**Edit**

In response to a deleted comment asking why we don't just pass in the string name, the code used to look something like

```
            Class item = new Class  {
                ContactRelationId = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("ContactRelationId"))
                    ? (int?)null
                    : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ContactRelationId"))}
```

And the requirement passed down was that we should not store package procedures as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to send through the instance of the object that has the property, that is going to get that property set on it.  if your class looked like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int? MyInt { get; set; }
}
```

you'd have to send an instance to this method:

```
public static void GetNullableInt32(this DbDataReader reader, MyClass instance, string propName)
```

But why use reflection when you don't have to?  It's slower, can often lead to bugs.  Just do the assignment in the calling method:

```
public static void GetNullableInt32(this DbDataReader reader, string propName)
{
   //...
}

//calling method
myClassInstance.MyInt = reader.GetNullableInt32(nameof(MyClass.MyInt));
```

all this assumes that your column names and property names are identical, as you seem to have specified they are.